# Wamp Server and Python

Tags: python, database, wampserver

Hi i have installed WAMP server(Mysql , apache ,php) and also installed "Python" separately.Now i am trying to connect to that database using python code .

This is my python code:

```
#!C:\Python32\python.exe
import sys
import os
import cgi
import MySQLdb
import cgitb
import SecureDb
cgitb.enable()
print ("Content-type: text/plain\n\n");
conn= MySQLdb.connect(host = SecureDb.host ,user =SecureDb.user ,passwd=SecureDb.password ,db=SecureDb.database)
cursor=conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("select * from register where Name='Subburaj'")
result=cursor.fetchall()
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

But this is showing an error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ponmani\Desktop\test.cgi", line 5, in <module>
    import MySQLdb
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from release import __version__, version_info, __author__
ImportError: No module named release
```

If anybody came across this problem please help me to solve this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's odd- line 2 in the traceback doesn't match line 2 in the file. Are you sure what you're showing us is the contents of `C:\Users\Ponmani\Desktop\test.cgi`?

Comment: Sorry  David Robinson..Now u can see my edited post..

Answer (score 2):

MYSQLdb doesn't come with python. It seems that you have to install it first from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/). There's an executable [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/files/latest/download), if you are using windows 32. But it's for python 2.7. If you are using python 3.2 it gets more difficult. [Here's](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) an unofficial package that should work for 3.2.

EDIT:
Release module should be a part of mysqldb, my only guess is theres is still something wrong with the installation. Maybe subforlders weren't extracted correctly.You should try to reinstall.

EDIT: you can also check if you have release.py in the mysqldb directory. if you dont it is surely installation problem.

Comment: root in that link i cant see any downloadable file??

Comment: Thanks root ,,now i installed Mysql inside python folder,this error is gone.Now it showing some other error.See my edited post.

Comment: how did you install it? using an executable or smth else?

Comment: Root i have  release.py ..It has the required information.But i don't know y this is happening??\

Comment: i think you should try to reinstall and if it doesn't work. post a separate question with the import error in the heading.

Comment: sorry, can't help there. if you post a separate question, maybe someone can. or you could install python 2.7 and have a new go with a different mysqldb version.

Answer (score 1):

You Need to install MySQLdb Module

```
easy_install MySQL-python
```

Comment: On the Command Line Prompt. If You have not installed easy_install download and install it from http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools